# Remove blank line in .csv files

Tags: batch-file, csv, cmd, export-to-csv

I am running a batch file that creates a csv file containing information about disks, but the resulting csv file starts with a blank line which causes me some problems. Any way I can modify my bat file to *not* create this extra blank line?

My bat file looks like this:

```
wmic /node:"(machinename)" logicaldisk get size,freespace,caption /format:CSV > disks.csv
```

Comment: If you were on Linux or have the Cygwin tools, `tail "+2"` will copy text in a pipeline omitting the first line, as would `gawk -F, 'NF>0 {print} '`, which would only print lines having at least one comma seperated field.

Comment: @Paul If she's using batch, I doubt shes in linux

Comment: Maybe overkill:  http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/ has a gawk for windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter the lines

```
wmic /node:"(machinename)" ^
  logicaldisk get size,freespace,caption ^
  /format:CSV | find "," > disks.csv
```

As you are requesting the data as csv, filter to only get the lines with commas inside.